# For all non-negative random variables, why is $X=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbf 1_{X\geq t}\,\mathrm dt$ true?

Tags: probability

I am wondering why this equation is necessarily true for all non-negative random variables:

$$
X=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbf 1_{X\geq t}\,\mathrm dt
$$

What is confusing me is that It appears that the indicator function only spits out a value of $1$ and that I am not seeing the connection here and how the integral over the indicator function makes it $X$. Thanks!

Comment: $\int_0^\infty 1_{x \ge t} dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1_{t \in [0,x]}  dt = \int_0^x dt = x$ (if $x \ge 0$)

Comment: I believe you meant to write $\mathbb E[X]$ on the left-hand side and not $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing why you would be confused unless you are trying to integrate with respect to $X$ instead of $t$.

$$\int\limits_{0}^\infty\mathbf 1_{X>t}\operatorname d t~=~\int\limits_{0}^\infty\mathbf 1_{t<X}\operatorname d t ~=~ \int\limits_0^{\max\{X,0\}}\operatorname d t ~=~ \max\{X,0\}$$

Which is of course $X$ when $X>0$

Comment: The notation $X>t$ is shorthand for $\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)>t\}$. Since we are not given a value of $\omega$ at which to evaluate $X$, or integrating over (a subset of) the sample space with respect to $\omega$, it doesn't make sense to compare $X$ and $t$ here. What would it mean for a function to be greater than a real number?

Comment: @Math1000  Indeed a random variable is a function (by definition), and thus $\mathbf 1_{X>t}$ is also function; one evaluating to $1$ whenever the random variable evaluates to greater than the constant, and $0$ elsewhen.  Thus the entire integral turns out to be a function too, which for a strictly positive random variable, this function is the random variable.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty \mathbf 1_{X>t}\operatorname d t$ is notational shorthand for $$\omega \mapsto \int_0^\infty \mathbf 1_{X(\omega)>t}\operatorname d t$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation you wrote does not make sense since the LHS is a random variable and RHS is a real number. Such an expression can only be used inside a $\Pr[]$, which denotes the probability of the random variable $X$ equaling the real value.

What you can say is that for all $x\in\mathrm{supp}(X)$, we have
$$
x=\int_{0}^\infty \mathbf 1_{x\geq t}\,\mathrm{d}t\,.
$$

As you can see, this statement has nothing to do with the random variable $X$, but each point in its support, which is only a nonnegative real number.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the result you are interested in here; what you have written is not well-defined.

If $\mathbb P(X\geqslant0)=1$, then the map $(t,\omega)\mapsto \mathsf 1_{X(\omega)>t}$ defined on $[0,\infty)\times\Omega$ is measurable and nonnegative, hence by Tonelli's theorem we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= \int_\Omega X(\omega)\,\mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega)\\
&= \int_\Omega\int_0^{X(\omega)} \mathsf dt\,\mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega)\\
&= \int_\Omega \int_{[0,\infty)} \mathsf 1_{X(\omega)>t} \mathsf dt\,\mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega) \\
&= \int_{[0,\infty)} \int_{\Omega} \mathsf 1_{X(\omega)>t} \mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega)\,\mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X>t)\,\mathsf dt.
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain what have you done? And also, could you prove that without Tonelli's Theorem?